# Where did the Valentine outfitter/clothier go?

Tags: red-dead-redemption-2

On my first trip into Valentine I visited an outfitter's shop to buy some new clothes, but didn't have a lot of money so didn't buy anything. Upon returning later in the game with some cash, I can't find the Outfitter anywhere. It's not marked on the map, and the map legend doesn't include an entry for it.

Can anyone remind me where it is or know why it has gone?

Answer (score 6):

Clothes can be purchased from the General Store in Valentine. Leaving the Stables and heading up the street, it's the first building on the left.

[image: Map of Valentine]

View the Catalogue and you can browse to clothes and preview them before buying.

Comment: Thank you SO much, I thought I had imagined the whole thing!